Supabase Auth email_address_not_authorized
I am trying to create a user account via an admin dashboard I created for my database:
 const { data: userData, error: userError } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
        email: data.userEmail,
        password: data.password,
      });

Whenever I run this, I get the following error:

email_address_not_authorized

I can't find any documentation on this error.

Supabase says you need to setup custom SMTP provider for your project. The signup request fails because supabase will only send verification email to members of the organization while no custom SMTP provider is setup.
Here is a link to the documentation of the error
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/debugging/error-codes

The issue was that I was not using the admin SDK so it was trying to sign up a new account while I was already signed in.
Working code:
const { data: userData, error: userError } = await supabase.auth.admin.createUser({
        email: data.userEmail,
        password: data.password,
      });


getting:
AuthApiError: User not allowed
